# Integer division problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> For any positive integer $a$, find the least positive integer $n$ for which the formula below produces an integer result
>
> $$\frac {a-n}{2n+1}$$
>
> except for the trivial solutions with $n$ being $0$ or $a$.

I'm a beginner in discrete math, so I'm clueless from which direction to approach this problem in order to solve it.

Comment: $(2n+1)|(a-n)\iff (2n+1)$ will divide $\{2(a-n)+2n+1\}=2a+1$

Comment: Note that such a positive integer $n$ does not exist for all positive integers $a$.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks. As I understand it, the piece within curly brackets is a set that is the left part of an equation, right? But I still cannot see what should I do to find the $n$ for a given $a$. Would you please be so kind to explain the process?

Comment: @DesmondHume, I meant $$2(a-n)+2n+1=2a+1$$ will be divisible by $2n+1$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I get it now, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 2n\!+\!1\!:\,\ 2n\equiv-1\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{n\equiv -\dfrac{1}2}\ \, $ so $\ \ 0\equiv a\!\color{#c00}{-\!n} \equiv a+\color{#c00}{\dfrac{1}2}\overset{\large\rm\ \times\ 2}\iff 0\equiv 2a\!+\!1$

**Alternatively** if modular fractions are unfamilar we can scale the above by $2$ yielding

$\qquad\  {\rm mod}\ 2n\!+\!1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{2n\equiv -1},\ \ 0\equiv a-n\overset{\rm\large times\ 2}\iff 0\equiv 2a\color{#c00}{-2n}\equiv 2a\color{#c00}{+1}$

The reverse direction $\,(\Leftarrow)\,$ arises by scaling by $\,\color{#c00}{2^{-1}\equiv -n}.$

**Alternatively** if congruences are unfamiliar, rewriting the above using divisibility

$$\ 2n\!+\!1\mid a\!-\!n\color{#c00}\iff 2n\!+\!1\mid 2(a\!-\!n)\iff 2n\!+\!1\mid 2(a\!-\!n)+(2n\!+\!1) = 2a+1$$

because $\ 2n\!+\!1\mid \color{#0a0}{2k}\,\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\, 2n\!+\!1\mid  k = -\color{#0a0}{2k}n + k(2n\!+\!1),\,$ or, since $\,2n\!+\!1\,$ and $\,2\,$ are coprime, therefore $\,2^{-1}\,$ exists mod $\,2n\!+\!1.$

Comment: Thank you for this info, but as a beginner I'm having hard time grasping it. Could please help me derive the actual solution, perhaps an algorithmic one?

Comment: @Desmond By the above $\,2n\!+\!1\,$ divides $\,a\!-\!n\,$ iff it divides $\,2a+1,\,$ so it amounts to finding the least proper divisor of $\,2a+1,\,$ i.e. its least prime factor (necessarily odd). If you tell me *specifically* which parts are not clear then I can elaborate.

Comment: And is there an efficient way of finding the least prime factor of an arbitrary number?

Comment: @Desmond That's equivalent to integer factorization, which is generally quite hard.

Comment: Great explanations. Thanks again. Not being able to find a solution is a huge bummer though..